# module 'torch' has no attribute 'nan_to_num'

Tags: python, pytorch, attributeerror

I am using 1.7.1 version of Pytorch on Ubuntu, and I try to do the following :

```
x = torch.tensor([float('nan'), float('inf'), -float('inf'), 3.14])
torch.nan_to_num(x)
```

but I am getting this error :

`AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'nan_to_num'`

But it does exist in the documentation since I just copied those 2 lines from it. Can someone help me ?

Comment: `nan_to_num` works for 1.8+

Comment: update Pytorch, and try again

Answer (score 2):

`nan_to_num` was introduced in PyTorch [1.8](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/equivalent-to-numpys-nan-to-num/52448/4?u=iacob). You will need to update your torch package to access it:

```
pip install --upgrade torch
```